# jQuery change FIELDSET depending on RADIO BUTTON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to implement the following code.
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Chaaampy/pen/mpgLmm?editors=1010)
But the difference I want is that whenever the user clicks red it will skip the next step and jump to another step.
For example, if at step 1 I click red then it will skip step 2 and move on to step 3.
In the javascript code I added condition if the value of red is more than 1 then

```
next_fs.hide();
next_fs.show();
```

According to my very little knowledge its supposed to work. At this point i have no idea what i am supposed to do.

Comment: Is it always jump to 3 step? If not you need any mapping when go where.

Comment: Manipulate anywhere I want according to the options selected. just for example I mentioned step 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below code.

```
 if($(this).parent().find('.control-checkbox input:checked').val() == "red"){
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next().next();
    }else{
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
  }
```

Add above code in next click function.

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
  //console.log($(this).parent().find('.control-checkbox input:checked').val());
  if($(this).parent().find('.control-checkbox input:checked').val() == "red"){
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next().next();
    }else{
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
  }
    // activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    // show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    // hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            // as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            // 1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            // 2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            // 3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        // this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

previous click. please update below code.

```
 if($(this).parent().prev().prev().find('.control-checkbox input:checked').val() == "red"){
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev().prev();
    }else{
      previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
  }
```

Add above code in previous click function.

```
$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();

  //console.log($(this).parent().prev().prev().find('.control-checkbox input:checked').val());
  if($(this).parent().prev().prev().find('.control-checkbox input:checked').val() == "red"){
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev().prev();
    }else{
      previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
  }

    // de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    // show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    // hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            // as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            // 1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            // 2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            // 3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        // this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

Comment: But the problem here is if i click back it goes to step 2 which it should o back to step 1

Comment: @taufeeqzaman see my answer, does exactly what you want and is dynamic

Comment: @taufeeqzaman I have updated the previous click function. Please check above code.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a data attribute to the inputs, like `data-skip="2"`. Basically say "if this is selected, skip 2". Then, instead of `$(this).parent().next()` you check the selected value in the current step and select the next view with `$(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, skipSteps).last()`.

So for example you would have this:

```javascript
current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_step = current_fs.find('input:checked').attr('data-skip') || 1;
next_fs = $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, parseInt(next_step, 10)).last();
```

Check my fork: https://codepen.io/tbleckert/pen/aRLLwE?editors=1010